# Approx how much does battery life suffer with allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled: CLLocationDistanceMax:CLTimeIntervalMax

Tags: ios

Does anybody have any sort of rough metrics for how much calling allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled: effects battery life when the parameters supplied are CLLocationDistanceMax and CLTimeIntervalMax?